# DateTimePicker calculate so the second interacts with the first datetimepicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'am trying to let one DateTimePicker interact with another one, so if you select something like: 08-08-2013, then the Mindate function of the second DateTimePicker needs to be that date, I tried using this code, but this code won't work:

```
    private void datetimepicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datetimepicker2.MinDate = datetimepicker1.Value.Date;
    }
```

Does anybody has an idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "this code won't work" What didn't work? Did it throw an error?

Comment: Value of '1/31/2002 12:00:00 ' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'.
Parameter name: Value

Comment: Congratulations, it works.  It you expect this to prevent the user from picking a date less than MinDate then you have the wrong expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently written the same style of code, I have 2 DateTime Pickers set with a custom format.

The code I have and which works is

```
EndDate.MinDate = StartDate.Value;
StartDate.MaxDate = EndDate.Value;
```

I believe it is the `.Date` that is causing the discrepancy in yours, as it is the only difference